# MySQL Delete trigger for deleting new data off new table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables with the same structure on different databases. I want to create a delete trigger on the old table so it deletes data off of the new table whenever there is a delete on the old table.

Any help is appreciated.
No external links, please!!!

```
MariaDB [test]> show create table test.new_table\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: new_table
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `day_of_week` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hour_of_day` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `idx` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clicks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conversions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`day_of_week`,`hour_of_day`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> show create table db.table\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: table
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `day_of_week` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hour_of_day` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `idx` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clicks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conversions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`day_of_week`,`hour_of_day`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You're supposed to show the code that you've tried. That's probably why you've been voted down. You're unlikely to get any help unless you make more of an effort.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem.

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER table_del 
        AFTER DELETE ON a.table 
        FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN
        DELETE IGNORE FROM test.table_new where test.table_new.id <=> old.id and test.table_new.day_of_week <=> old.day_of_week  and test.table_new.hour_of_day <=> old.hour_of_day;
        END; //
    DELIMITER ;
```